# HttpClient.Get can't return Observable<boolean>

Tags: angular, typescript

Using angular 5.1.

Returning an `Observable` of any object works

```
getGlassPartsForVin(vin: string): Observable<GlassPartsResponse> {
  return this.httpClient.get<GlassPartsResponse>(
    `/api/vin/${vin}`,
    this.getRequestOptions()
  );
}
```

Returning boolean or int doesn't:

```
getHasAccess(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.httpClient.get<boolean>(
    "api/permission/hasaccess",
    this.getRequestOptions());
}
```

Throws:

```
error TS2322: Type 'Observable<HttpEvent<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.
  Type 'HttpEvent<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

What am I supposed to do if all I get back from the api is just `true` or `false`?

**EDIT:** repro https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mzgfdg
vscode give a bit more info, seems to be a matter of boolean`not being`object`

```
Type 'Observable<HttpEvent<Boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Observable<Boolean>'.
  Type 'Observable<HttpEvent<Boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Boolean>'.
    Type 'HttpEvent<Boolean>' is not assignable to type 'Boolean'.
      Type 'HttpSentEvent' is not assignable to type 'Boolean'.
        Types of property 'valueOf' are incompatible.
          Type '() => Object' is not assignable to type '() => boolean'.
            Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

**EDIT2:** I fixed it by returning `{ headers: HttpHeaders }` in the `getRequestOptions()` method, instead of `any`. With this I've started using this method signature:

```
get<T>(url: string, options?: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
        };
        observe?: 'body';
        params?: HttpParams | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
        };
        reportProgress?: boolean;
        responseType?: 'json';
        withCredentials?: boolean;
    }): Observable<T>;
```

Instead of this that I was using with the `any`:

```
get<T>(url: string, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    observe: 'events';
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | string[];
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'json';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<HttpEvent<T>>;
```

I'm still a bit confused on how that made a difference

Comment: `this.getRequestOptions()` seems be the problem in the code posted. as it is not defined.

Comment: Was going to say the same as @davidxxx. Your issue is with the request options !

Comment: That is true, however the other error shown there is the same. weirdly enough if I remove that line the error goes away. I think it may be dues to the `options` being of type `any`

Comment: I've updated the link to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

```
getHasAccess(): Observable<boolean> {
return this.httpClient.get("api/permission/hasaccess", this.getRequestOptions()).map(res =>{
    if(res.condition)
      return true;
    else
      return false
  })
}
```

I'm pretty sure this will work. Just check whatever condition you need as the result and then return the boolean yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can either type it to `any`, or maybe use the correspondign interfaces `Boolean` or `Integer`.

Your autocompletion will take the information of the return of your function, not the type of your call, so you should be good to go.

Comment: And to be honest, it's a bit weird, because I just tested it and I had no issue returning a boolean.

Comment: You running angular 5 and HttpClient?

Comment: Yes I am : `constructor(
    private session: SessionService,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { super(); }`

Comment: `Boolean` doesn't seems to be solving the issue because the `.get` method still returns `HttpEvent<T>`. I don't know what is it that allows me to return more complex objects straight away in other cases

Comment: What happens if you don't type your call ? simply `get()` instead of `get<T>()` ?

Comment: You can try `getHasAccess(): Observable<boolean> | boolean`.. But this looks like an authorization function, in which case I would create an interface that encapsulates ALL permissions the app will have and use that as the Observed type. Even if "hasAccess" is the only permission right now, as the app expands, permissions most likely will as well.

Comment: `get()` does pretty much the same.

Comment: From your Blitz, it seems your options are the issue.